# Triggers in core data

Tags: ios, sql, database, core-data, triggers

How can I create triggers or something equivalent for core data model in my app?
My core data model have many entities and these entities are not in any relationship.
I want to fire a trigger whenever a new data is added or whenever data is modified in core data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSFetchResultController in this kind of situations. You can find more detail in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to achieve this.

According to Apple's documentation:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results
>   returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a
>   UITableView object.

Here's a nice tutorial to get you started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller